# Reset all variables (please change if wrong term) in python script

Tags: python, loops

When there is a failure in the code, I would like the code to reset and run again.  I think I have the ability to do this, however when the code resets on a failure it does not clear the value of x.  Because of this, the code will just continue as it left off negating the reason for the return to start.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import os
import glob

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('directory_on_computer')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
browser.get('a_website')

time.sleep(8)

browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").clear()
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_UserName").send_keys("user")
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").clear()
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_password").send_keys("pass")
browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_login_login").click()

try:
    ReportMgr= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Report Manager')
    ReportMgr.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    CustomReport= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Custom Report')
    CustomReport.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management')
    ProgramManagement.click()
    ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)

########testing area below


########Save below

    for x in range(1, 71):
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
        time.sleep(120)
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN * x, Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(120)   
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_ImageAnchor > img").click()
        time.sleep(120)    
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').click()
        time.sleep(120)

except: 
  pass
```

Comment: The correct term would be “restart”. And no, I’m not kidding.

Comment: It would be better to use a loop, and define all your variables inside, but a fast, easy solution would be `execfile(__file__)`.  (in Python2)

Comment: I feel like an idiot here....but you would just slap in "restart" at the bottom of the code?

Comment: @Yogwhatup No, I would probably do what zondo suggested. But *if* a complete clean-up of the program’s memory space is what you’re after then, yes, the answer is: this is accomplished by a restart.

Comment: @konrad-rudolph Ok - so the last bit of code would be: Restart except: pass?  It sound like what I want - I don't even care if this thing continues to run in an infinite loop.  I just want to make sure all variables are reset when the code starts over. Also I want to give you "props" if this works.  Submit this as an answer and I will up-vote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not a total reset is needed, but a reset of local, self defined variables, create a function and make use of the function namespace. Then just call the function in a loop and leave the loop for a restart.

#### Edit 13th Mar 2016

```
#do one-time imports here

def exec_code():
    ## define local vars at the beginning of the code
    counter = 0    ## counter is local to the function and dropped when leaving the func

    ## arbitrary function code
    while True:
        counter += 2
        print "counter is %i, ending at 10" % counter
        answer = raw_input("Restart? (Enter 'y'+return to restart): ")

        if answer == "y": 
            return True      ##  Return True to exit the function and restart

        if counter >= 10:
            return False     ##  Return False or None to exit the loop and do not restart

while exec_code(): pass
```

Comment: so something like x=1 at the end to reset the variable to 1?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and didn't know where to find comments. I just found it.